# Disable copy function in PDFTRON for Android

Tags: pdftron

Is it possible to disable the copy option of the lib when selecting a text in the PDF using the PDFTron lib for Android?
I tried to search for the string, but also have not found it.

Comment: for the general understanding on how it works see section 9.10 of the PDF spec(extraction of text content). It could be achived for exmaple, by using embedded font with custom encoding without a unicode mapping entry(toUnicode cmap). I don't know how to do it with this library, but other libraries can do it well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using one of the mobile SDK's, or using our PDFViewWPF control for .Net 4+, then this is possible by modifying the tools code that is provided. There will one or two text selection tools, for which you can just comment out. Plus you would want to disable ctrl-c, and right click and select copy abilities. Exact code changes depends on platform. If you are using our older C++ PDFViewCtrl class this is harder to do, but I suspect you are not on this anyway.

Be aware though, there is no real way to prevent a user from extracting text from a PDF, since they can always open it in another PDF viewer and do it there.

See this form post for more info, including how to scramble the unicode values of text.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/pdfnet-sdk/disable$20text/pdfnet-sdk/luWQmyhRDTw/z7UIGuu9uYkJ

Note, you will probably be interested in the **[PDFTron WebViewer](https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/showcase/)** technology, which provides much greater control over content. In particular, the original PDF file is never exposed to anyone for download. You can also encrypt the XOD file, so it cannot be opened in an XPS viewer, and you have full control over the UI, including disabling text search/extraction.

https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/showcase/

https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I forgot to specify that I'm refering the Android version of the lib. I already found the code line where I can do it, I will post the solution here when I'm done.